# protect a file using .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a file to protect using .htaccess in my site. My site is build on wordpress, and it has already an .htaccess file, the file I want to protect is in the same directory as the .htaccess file so it means I can't create another .htaccess file.

code in the current .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

How can I insert the below code, to the code above?

```
<FilesMatch file.php>
AuthName "Restricted File"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/the/.htpasswd
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

I tried inserting it below the comment #END wordpress but it doesn't popup a box when I tried to access the file. I even used `<Files> </Files>` and tried to insert it inside the `<IfModule></IfModule>` and still no luck. can any body has experience in using the .htaccess file?

Comment: Did you also create a file called `.htpasswd` placed at the same location as `.htaccess`?

Comment: yes I created it. I have placed it in a different location.

Comment: Place it before `# BEGIN WordPress` line.

Comment: @anubhava no luck. :(

Comment: So you're not getting any auth dialog for `file.php`?

Comment: @anubhava nope...but I have found an answer will post it later.

Comment: I found answers in here : [this link](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/prevent-unauthorized-wp-admin-wp-login-php-attempts)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the Auth doesn't work because the apache module responsible for it is disabled.

Check if your apache module **mod_authn_core** is enabled. Run in console

```
apache2ctl -M
```

If the Module is not enabled, just enable it:

```
sudo a2enmod mod_authn_core
```